# Перевод экранных координат в мировые

Tags: java, opengl, opengles, lwjgl

При переводе координат у меня почему то не учитывается матрица `View`:

```
private Vector3f getCoord(MouseInput mouseInput, float z) {
        int wdwWitdh = 800;
        int wdwHeight = 800;
        Vector2d mousePos = mouseInput.getCurrentPos();
        float x = (float) (2 * mousePos.x) / (float) wdwWitdh - 1.0f;
        float y = 1.0f - (float) (2 * mousePos.y) / (float) wdwHeight;
        Matrix4f invProjectionMatrix = new Matrix4f();
        Matrix4f invViewMatrix = new Matrix4f();
        Vector4f tmpVec = new Vector4f();
        invProjectionMatrix.set(p);
        invProjectionMatrix.invert();
        tmpVec.set(x, y, z, 1.0f);
        tmpVec.mul(invProjectionMatrix);
        tmpVec.z = z;
        tmpVec.w = 0.0f;
        invViewMatrix.set(view);
        invViewMatrix.invert();
        tmpVec.mul(invViewMatrix);
        return new Vector3f(tmpVec.x, tmpVec.y, z);
    }
```

**Рендеринг луча:**

```
   private void rectangleRay(MouseInput mouseInput) {
        glUseProgram(rayProgram);

        FloatBuffer vi = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
        view.get(vi);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(rayProgram, "projectionMatrix"), false, pMatrix);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(rayProgram, "modelViewMatrix"), false, vi);
        glBindVertexArray(vaoRay);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, rayBuffer);//pointbuffer-камера, точка помещаем ее в буффер
        if (originRay != null && !mouseInput.isLeftButtonPressed()) {
            glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(3 * 2 * Float.BYTES).put(new float[]{
                    originRay.x, originRay.y, pz, originRay.x, originRay.y, cz
            }).rewind(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
            glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
            originRay = null;
        }
        drawLine(2);
    }
```

Координаты view в начале:

```
Vector3f cameraPosition = new Vector3f(0, 0, 1);
 FloatBuffer vMatrix = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
        view = new Matrix4f();
        view.lookAt(cameraPosition.x, cameraPosition.y, cameraPosition.z,
                0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f).get(vMatrix);
```

**Как у меня меняется координаты камеры, когда я ее прокручиваю:**

wnd.setKeyListener((key, scancode, action) -> {
       Vector3f  whatToMove = render.cameraPosition;
        float step = 0.1f;

```
    switch (key) {
        case GLFW_KEY_W:
            whatToMove.add(0, step, 0);
            break;
        case GLFW_KEY_S:
            whatToMove.sub(0, step, 0);
            break;
        case GLFW_KEY_A:
            whatToMove.sub(step, 0, 0);
            break;
        case GLFW_KEY_D:
            whatToMove.add(step, 0, 0);
            break;
        case GLFW_KEY_Q:
            whatToMove.sub(0, 0, step);
            break;
        case GLFW_KEY_E:
            whatToMove.add(0, 0, step);
            break;
    }
```

При первом запуске луч в ортогональной проекции проецируется в точку(правильно),далее я начинаю вертеть камеру, изменяя матрицу **view**.

**Вывод при первом запуске: (розовый полигон означает, что луч находится там)**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После того как прокрутил камеру и создал новый луч, луч уже не проецируется в точку(не правильно), а выводится вот так. (синяя линия это луч):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: open gl считает, что камера находится в координатах 0 0 1 , что не правильно

Comment: А как вы крутите камеру, приведите пожалуйста код.

Comment: 2 точки для луча вы получаете из одной, различаются они только координтой Z (originRay.x, originRay.y, pz, originRay.x, originRay.y, cz, ). Видимо ваш луч в мировых координатах и в результате он начинается в рассчитаной вами точке и направлен вдоль оси Z.

Comment: @Unick Обновил вопрос

Comment: @Unick и как исправить?)

Comment: Видимо вам необходимо рассчитать 2 точки с разным z-ом в методе getCoord и уже по им строить точкам строить луч.

Comment: @Unick а зачем разный z  если глубина мне нужна одинаковая?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77629/discussion-between-unick-and-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы построить луч выделения, необходимо найти 2 точки на нём. Для этого необходимо использовать функцию getCoord с разными значениями z. Например -1 и 0.

Также стоит изменить функцию rectangleRay, чтобы она использовала рассчитаные точки.

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(3 * 2 * Float.BYTES).put(
             new float[]{ originRay.x, originRay.y, originRay.z, 
                          originRay2.x, originRay2.y, originRay2.z}).rewind(), 
             GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Comment: а не подскажите как можно получить нормаль камеры?

Comment: аа там просто достаточно умножить на -1 на view координаты